# Install(rollback) to older socket.IO version

Tags: node.js, socket.io, npm

I am currently running version 0.9.16 of socket.IO and need to rollback to version 0.9.0

Can I simply install on top of my newer version using `npm install socket.io@0.9.0` ?

Or do I need to uninstall the newer version first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have not installed the package globally (i.e. with '-g'), you can just delete the socket.io folder in node_modules and run npm install again with your desired version of socket.io.

Or you could do:

```
npm uninstall socket.io@0.9.16
npm install socket.io@0.9.0
```